# Split string with a single occurence (not twice) of a delimiter in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, split

This is better explained with an example. I want to achieve an split like this:

`two-separate-tokens-this--is--just--one--token-another`

->

`["two", "separate", "tokens", "this--is--just--one--token", "another"]`

I naively tried `str.split(/-(?!-)/)` and it won't match the first occurrence of double delimiters, but it will match the second (as it is not followed by the delimiter):

`["two", "separate", "tokens", "this-", "is-", "just-", "one-", "token", "another"]`

Do I have a better alternative than looping through the string?

By the way, the next step should be replacing the two consecutive delimiters by just one, so it's kind of escaping the delimiter by repeating it... So the final result would be this:

`["two", "separate", "tokens", "this-is-just-one-token", "another"]`

If that can be achieved in just one step, that should be really awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the regular expressions weren't very good with edge cases (like 5 consecutive delimiters) and I had to deal with replacing the double delimiters with a single one (and then again it would get tricky because `'----'.replace('--', '-')` gives `'---'` rather than `'--'`)
 I wrote a function that loops over the characters and does everything in one go (although I'm concerned that using the string accumulator can be slow :-s)

```
f = function(id, delim) {
    var result = [];
    var acc = '';
    var i = 0;
    while(i < id.length) {
        if (id[i] == delim) {
            if (id[i+1] == delim) {
                acc += delim;
                i++;
            } else {
                result.push(acc);
                acc = '';
            }
        } else {
            acc += id[i];
        }
        i++;
    }

    if (acc != '') {
        result.push(acc);
    }

    return result;
    }
```

and some tests:

```
> f('a-b--', '-')
["a", "b-"]
> f('a-b---', '-')
["a", "b-"]
> f('a-b---c', '-')
["a", "b-", "c"]
> f('a-b----c', '-')
["a", "b--c"]
> f('a-b----c-', '-')
["a", "b--c"]
> f('a-b----c-d', '-')
["a", "b--c", "d"]
> f('a-b-----c-d', '-')
["a", "b--", "c", "d"]
```

(If the last token is empty, it's meant to be skipped)

Answer (score 8):

<strike>`str.match(/(?!-)(.*?[^\-])(?=(?:-(?!-)|$))/g);`</strike>

<strike>Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/yMjTF/) fiddle.</strike>

---

<strike>*Explanation:*</strike>

Non-greedy pattern `(?!-)(.*?[^\-])` match a string that does not start and does not end with dash character and pattern `(?=(?:-(?!-)|$))` requires such match to be followed by single dash character or by end of line. Modifier `/g` forces function `match` to find all occurrences, not just a single (first) one.

---

***Edit*** *(based on OP's comment):*

`str.match(/(?:[^\-]|--)+/g);`

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jxCWR/) fiddle.

*Explanation:*

Pattern `(?:[^\-]|--)` will match non-dash character or double-dash string. Sign `+` says that such matching from the previous pattern should be multiplied as many times as can. Modifier `/g` forces function `match` to find all occurrences, not just a single (first) one.

*Note:*

*Pattern* `/(?:[^-]|--)+/g` *works in Javascript as well, but JSLint requires to escape `-` inside of square brackets, otherwise it comes with error.*

Comment: an explanation on how it works would be more than appreciated!

Comment: thanks... in fact I was confused because at first I didn't realize that it was a _match_ rather than a _split_ :)

Comment: it didn't work for this `'this--is-----a test'.match(/(?!-)(.*?[^\-])(?=(?:-(?!-)|$))/g);`, it returns `["this--is-----a test"]`

Comment: @fortran - Your question is not clear enough. See my updated answer for solution to your new input.

Comment: Worked for me!  I am using pipe character | as a delimiter, unless they want to use the pipe, in which case the user enters a double pipe ||.

if (value && maxAllowed > 1) {
  value = value.match(/(?:[^\|]|\|\|)+/gm).map((val) => val.replace('||', '|').trim());
}

Answer (score 2):

You would need a negative lookbehind assertion as well as your negative lookahead:

```
(?<!-)-(?!-)
```

http://regexr.com?31qrn

Unfortunately the javascript regular expression parser does not support negative lookbehinds, I believe the only workaround is to inspect your results afterwards and remove any matches that would have failed the lookbehind assertion (or in this case, combine them back into a single match).

Comment: -1 : You offered a solution that you know is not going to work with Javascript, so what is a benefit of such post?

Comment: Actually is was beneficial since it helped me get to the correct solution.

Comment: Providing an answer is about educating people just as much (if not more) than it's about providing a working copy-paste solution.

Comment: @jbabey - yes, but you should offer some working solution (if exists)

Answer (score 2):

@Ωmega has the right idea in using `match` instead of `split`, but his regex is more complicated than it needs to be.  Try this one:

```
s.match(/[^-]+(?:--[^-]+)*/g);
```

It reads exactly the way you expect it to work: Consume one or more non-hyphens, and if you encounter a double hyphen, consume that and go on consuming non-hyphens.  Repeat as necessary.

---

**EDIT:** Apparently the source string may contain runs of two *or more* consecutive hyphens, which should not be treated as delimiters.  That can be handled by adding a `+` to the second hyphen:

```
s.match(/[^-]+(?:--+[^-]+)*/g);
```

You can also use a `{min,max}` quantifier:

```
s.match(/[^-]+(?:-{2,}[^-]+)*/g);
```

Comment: `'this--is-----a test'.match(/[^-]+(?:--[^-]+)*/g);` gives `["this--is", "a test"]` and I'd expect to preserve the dashes after `is` :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it purely with the regex engine in JS.  You could do it this way that is a little less involved than manually parsing:

```
var str = "two-separate-tokens-this--is--just--one--token-another";
str = str.replace(/--/g, "#!!#");
var split = str.split(/-/);
for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
    split[i] = split[i].replace(/#!!#/g, "--");
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/hAhAB/

Comment: -1 : This is not a general solution, as you always need some pattern that is not going to be in input string.

Comment: @Ωmega - Yes, you have to have a unique pattern to make this work, but I've always known enough about the acceptable input being used in my apps for this technique to work flawlessly.  Personally I find this type of solution much more maintainable and understandable than a long regex that I copied from somewhere and don't understand.  That's probably not the case for you, but is something others should think about.

Comment: @jfriend00 - Not understanding some regex pattern is a good reason to learn something about it. It is smarter to learn something new that works and is fast rather than use some slow approach. I hope you learnt something as well :)

Comment: @Ωmega - regex's are definitely useful in many ways and I use them regualrly, but I see people trying to shoehorn solutions into a regex that are not nearly as understandable or maintainable as something written with a few lines of regular javascript.  Your regex fits in that camp for me (that's not something I'm going to immediately recongize how it works in two years time).  You're welcome to your own opinion as am I.  My hierarchy of needs in programming is "correct", then "reliable", then "obvious, easily maintainable and robust over time" and then "fast enough".

Comment: @Ωmega, what happens to your solution if dashes are used in the input string?

Comment: @JoeTuskan - You should test it... Single dash will be a separator, multiple dash pattern will be part of text, as required by OP.

Comment: @Ωmega, cross-reference is a hyphenated word. I can read sir :) I'm saying your solution is not general either since a dash is an acceptable input. And I didn't downvote for what little it's actually worth.

Comment: @JoeTuskan - Not for OP, Sir :) In the question it clearly says that single dash is a separator... You are welcome to offer your new and better solution, if you know some. Will be glad to vote.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this without negative lookbehind (as @jbabey mentioned these are not supported in JS) like that (inspired by [this article](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript)):

```
\b-\b
```

Comment: It would not work if there are non-word characters used, such as `!` - test your split with input `two-separate!-tokens-this--is--just--one--token-another`