# How to split a string based on single occurance of the delimiter?

Tags: javascript

I have a delimiter `$` seperated string created from individual components . 
I need to split it and get the components that formed the string . 
However there are corner cases where $ appears in the value itself breaking my split logic .

Example `bar,fo$o and zoo` are the components . So the string created is `bar$fo$o$zoo` . 
All is fine but I can't now split it using `$` because it gives me `bar,fo,o and zoo` as the components.

One way to solve this is use a delimiter that is complex and most likely not going to occur . But I am trying to solve this using escaping . Replace `$` in tthe components with `$$` . Hence input components are now `bar,fo$$o,zoo` . Concatenated string is `bar$fo$$o$zoo` . 
Now how do I split if basis single occurrence of `$` in javascript ?

I am reading [Split string with a single occurence (not twice) of a delimiter in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939770/split-string-with-a-single-occurence-not-twice-of-a-delimiter-in-javascript) but it appears slightly complex . If its a duplicate question I will close it .

Comment: Why don't you use different delimiter?

Comment: As you pointed out, it seems duplicate of the question you posted. REGEX is definitely the way to go for this problem!

Comment: The answer to that question you linked to isn't very complex at all - just replace the `-`s with `$`. And yes, this is a duplicate of that.

Comment: @Pavlo And what happens when when one of the components needs to contain the new delimeter? You're just exchanging one problem for another.

Comment: @JLRishe : Regex is really difficult to decrypt sometimes :-) I am in a hurry as well to make sense out of that regex . Thanks will check it . Appreciate cross checking that and clarifying as I was reading that thinking it could be a duplicate .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my non-regexp solution to the problem;

```
var input = 'bar$fo$$o$zoo',
    results = input.replace(/%/g, '%25')
                   .replace(/\$\$/g, '%24')
                   .split('$')
                   .map(function(term) {
                       return decodeURIComponent(term);  
                   });

console.log(results);
```

You may try the fiddle at http://jsbin.com/qineqazaxo/2/edit

Comment: That won't work correctly when the input string is `The$url escaped version$of $$ is %24`

Comment: Thats true. I am thinking of an enhancement to the answer right now.

Comment: what about now, @JLRishe?

Comment: Yes, I think that will work.

Answer (score 1):

What about urlencoding the components?

```
encodeURIComponent('fo$o')
```

and then decodeURIComponent once you have split the string?

Comment: The problem is that it would also encode the separators so he would have the same problem again.

Comment: Yeah if that is the case this would not work at all!

Seems like he can modify the components before though?

At least thats what I understand from this qoute
"Replace $ in tthe components with $$ . Hence input components are now bar,fo$$o,zoo"