# Split strings based on single occurrence of delimiter but not double in Java

Tags: java, regex

How to split a string using single occurrence of a delimiter disregarding multiple occurrences?

For example, if the string contains
aaa, bbb,,ccc, ddd
I would like to split the string as follows:

aaa
bbb,,ccc
ddd

Tried using Regex with split() but unable to acquire the desired result.

Came across the solution in Javascript here: [Split string with a single occurence (not twice) of a delimiter in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939770/split-string-with-a-single-occurence-not-twice-of-a-delimiter-in-javascript). Is it possible to achieve the same in Java, with or without Regex?

Comment: Does a space follow the comma?

Comment: Could you show us what you tried with split()?

Comment: The spaces may or may not be present after/before a comma since the string's nature may vary. The string in question is obtained from the user and hence the presence/absence of space cannot be defined.

Comment: Have been trying to form a proper regex in split but haven't got past split("[,](?:[^,])|(?:[^,])[,]") which doesn't give the required results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String.split()` accepts regular expressions as delimiters so you could use the following pattern :

```
(?<!,),(?!,)
```

This regex matches a comma that is neither preceded nor followed by a comma.

You can see it in action here : https://ideone.com/CmtAzX

If you want to trim the leading spaces at the same time you can use `(?<!,),(?!,) *` as mentioned by Nicolas Filotto.

Comment: Probably not so efficient though, I think a solution without split could do better

Comment: I consider it good from regex point of view and i don't think there will be much of efficiency issue

Comment: @Araon the correct regexp is actually _(?<!,),(?!,) *_ otherwise you will have spaces in the result elements

Comment: @NicolasFilotto OP didn't mention aggregating spaces with the delimiter, but it indeed looks more natural. I edited my answer to mention your regex.

Comment: @Aaron if you check the output expected by the OP, you will see that there is no leading spaces

Answer (score 0):

Regex allows you to specify that a given symbol is neither preceded nor followed by another specified symbol. In your case you should use `(?<!,),(?!,)`. In general `(?<!x)y(?!z)` would find 'y' if it is neither preceeded by 'x' nor followed by 'z'.